# 18.04.3 LTS Keyboard backlight fails on Dell Inspiron 13 5370

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, backlight, inspiron

I have a Dell [Inspiron 13 5370](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-13-5370-laptop/docs) (non touchscreen version), running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and kernel "Linux 5.4.1-050401-generic".

The keyboard back light won't work. The shortcut key <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>  brings up the controls and cycles through the 3 levels (off, mid, full) but the keyboard backlights don't actually do anything. The only working light is the <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> LED indicator.  This experience was replicated with Lubuntu and Manjaro LiveUSBs.

The keyboard backlight works fine with Windows 10 once the driver is installed from Dell's website.

Tested the change recommended in below link. It does not appear to make a difference I used the 100s recommended it did say 63h. Rechecked after change and it shows 1m as suggested in article however keyboard back light still appears to not be functioning. 
https://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/sln308123/how-to-configure-the-keyboard-backlight-time-out-interval-in-ubuntu-linux?lang=en

Comment: I have tried the latest ubuntu 19 on a live USB same results controls appear and cycle through each level of brightness yet keyboard still doesn't light up....also checked my bios settings appear fine and they are set to work with the shortcut keys @K7AAY any other advise?

Comment: Sorry for the misread. Did not work with Lubuntu live either, or Manjora when tried had same result on live USB...Put windows 10 build on machine and works fine once driver installed from dell website

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln308123/how-to-configure-the-keyboard-backlight-time-out-interval-in-ubuntu-linux has a procedure to run through with AC power unplugged. Would you mind trying it? Please click [edit] to add the result of that test; do not use Add Comment, but instead click [edit].